# how can I call Sage from R?

Tags: r, sage

From searching, I see that calling `R` from `Sage` is pretty seamless. However, I cannot find information on calling `Sage` from `R`. For example, suppose that I have an `R` expression that I would like to differentiate, say

```
temp <- expression(x + x^2)
```

How can I send that to sage and have it differentiate it and send back an R expression? I would like the result to be pretty much equivalent to

```
D(temp,'x')
```

I have searched CRAN and google and have not found anything. I'm hoping there's a better solution than something based on the `system` function. I have seen that there is support from `R` for `yacas`, but I am interested in `Sage`.

I use 64-bit Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect there is not a solution other than `system` -- but will be pleasantly surprised if someone offers one.  It doesn't look like there's a very easy way to adapt the Sage "notebook server" to a simpler socket-based thing (as is used by `Ryacas`)

Comment: @BenBolker interesting, do you think there's a chance that there will be a package in the future or is the way that they're set up fundamentally incompatible?

Comment: I don't know, not having looked into it in detail, but at a glance it seems harder than integrating `yacas` -- looking briefly at the `yacas` documentation (`man yacas`), one quickly discovers a way to set up a client-server relationship, which communicates with the server via sockets.  A similarly quick look at Sage does not suggest a similarly easy strategy ... going via `rJython` as described below seems more fruitful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this would work, but Sage libraries can be imported into Python, and Python can be interfaced with the `rJython` package.  Could you call Sage functions through `rJython`? It might not be as clean as the `Ryacas` or `rSymPy` packages, but perhaps it will be good enough.

**Edit**
Since Sage uses SymPy, you could interface with SymPy directly:

```
require(rSymPy)
x <- Var('x') # Convenience function for: sympy("var(’x’)")
sympy("diff(x + x**2, x, 1)")
# [1] "1 + 2*x"
```

Comment: @jhetzel, interesting -- it looks like that's the only way. I wonder if it would be better to do that or through `system`. Thanks

Comment: @Xu Wang, I suppose the choice is your preference.  However, if you do use `rJython`, you can probably easily develop your own convenience wrapper functions, and then publish them as a package for future SageRs. You can have a look at the `rSymPy` package as an example, which I believe is a package of convenience functions for calling SymPy library functions through the `rJython` interface.

Comment: thanks, if you have some time, could you please show me how I would use your way to solve my example?

Comment: @Xu Wang, I'll try to put together a short example to get you started later tonight. In the meantime, you can view rSymPy's source code at: http://code.google.com/p/rsympy/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk .  The sympy.R functions seem to establish the rJython interface with the SymPy library, and the Sym.R functions look like they construct common SymPy commands for convenience.

Comment: thanks! Only do it if you have time and it's not a pain though.

Comment: @Xu Wang: Unfortunately, I've been unsuccessful so far with this strategy. Importing `sage.all` modules into python (except for sage's custom python `./sage -python`) always leads to errors with `libcsage.so` for me. I asked about it on 'Ask Sage', and William Stein, Sage's founder, replied that it probably can't be done this way ( http://ask.sagemath.org/question/897/from-sageall-import-results-in-libcsageso-cannot ).

Comment: @Xu Wang: Also, I believe that Sage uses SymPy for a lot of its CAS. So, if all you need is differentiation, you can just use `rSymPy`.

Comment: interesting. Well it was a good idea! I've been meaning to look into rSymPy so maybe now is the time. Thanks for your help!